# No Activity found to handle Intent act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-intent

I am following a tutorial and I have this error please help

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   `Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT
>   cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=image/* }`"

my class

```
public class Load_Image_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final int REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE = 0;
   ImageView image;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load__image_);

      image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE);
 }
}
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.app.soulhi.slider">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Load_Image_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What version of Android are you running on?

Comment: android studio 1.5.1

Comment: please show your manifest

Comment: What is the Android OS version you are working on ? Because it will not work before API level 19.

Comment: @Shadab  jelly bean 4.2.2 !!?  api 17

Comment: android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT will not work before API level 19

Comment: yes you are right  !  thank you .  i changed ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to ACTION_GET_CONTENT and it works

Answer (score 5):

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` was only added to the Android SDK with Android 4.4 (API Level 19). Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` on older devices.

This is covered somewhat in [the documentation on the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client).

Comment: unfortunately, our target minSdk now 21, and occurred the OP crash as well. Any suggestion or ideas or workaround to solve the issue?

Comment: @mochadwi: While most devices will support `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, not all will, such as Wear OS and Android TV. Google does not anticipate that users will want to be opening documents on those platforms. It is also possible that `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` will be unavailable for other reasons, such as a manufacturer screwing something up. There is not much that you can do about any of that, other than wrapping your `startActivityForResult()` call in a `try`/`catch` and handling the situation as best as you can.

Comment: Agreed with the `startActivityForResult` with `try`/`catch`. We just show toast now if `resolveActivity` not found for document reading in the users apps. Especially for the part of: ***manufacturer screwing something up.***